# Class and objects print all names in list that have specific word in title

Tags: python, class, object

So I have method to make to print all words that are in one object
So example I have def printall(listofmovies,word): , and i need to print all movies that have that word in their title (moviename)

so far i got this and im not sure if i done well

```
  def printall(listofmovies,word):
  word=len(word)
  for s in listofmovies:
    moviename=s.moviename
    for i in moviename:
      if(i==word[0])
        return(listofmovies,word[1:])
      else:
        return
  print(s.moviename)
```

Also thanks everyone who would help <3

Comment: After obtaining movie name you may check whether it contains the given word instead of opening a for loop.

Comment: I think you should give some example data and explain what you had and what you want.

Comment: So what if the title have 3 words or more, and i only need to find that one, should i split the s.moviename.split(" ") and see if the word is there ?

Comment: `split` is not needed. You may do `if word in moviename` or `moviename.find(word) > 0` and print the movie or put it in another container to print it later.

Comment: basically you have the "in" operator, if I got it right - you have a list of strings that each represente a movie name and you want to print all the names that includes a specific word? so you should loop over the list and ask: "if word in moviename[i] (gives true or false) print moviename[i].  It will help us if you will give an example

Comment: okay i have example, so if i have list of movies, and i only want to read the object that go for the title, it should go like this 
Moviename is "I like programming" and it need to read that moviename and see if the word "like" is in it, also i dont know that movie name, i only know word that need to see if it is in it

Comment: Perhaps, provide a sample Input and desired output in the question.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to clarify what you are asking? The code shown seems to deviate from the requirement on several key parts – for example, the code does not check whether the word appears in the moviename. Do you know how to check if a word occurs in  a string? Do you know the difference between ``return`` and ``print``? Is there a reason why you use recursion for this task?

Comment: could you write it as a code?  does each movie that stored in a list is a dictionary (whith a key of title for example)?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you would like something like this:

```
movies = ["Star Wars", "Star Trek", "Shrek"]

def printall(listofmovies, word):
    # Create a new list with all the titels that have 
    # the 'word' in titel using a list comprehension.
    # A list comprehension is a kind of 'shortcut' for 
    # creating lists
    match = [titel for titel in listofmovies if word in titel]

    # now that we have all the matches, let us print them
    # unpack all items in the list using * and print each of them
    # separated with a new line ('\n')
    print(*match, sep="\n")

printall(movies, "Star")
# Output: 
# Star Wars
# Star Trek
```